# HBase crashes after few seconds

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have been following the HBase installation instructions as given on this page:
https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart

I am using HBase version 1.1.3 (stable release) and have configured in standalone mode. I have installed OpenJDK 7

When I try to start hbase it crashes after few seconds and I get the following error:

```
2016-01-29 17:37:04,136 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master   exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2355)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.putInt(Bytes.java:899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.createByteArray(KeyValue.java:1082)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.<init>(KeyValue.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.<init>(KeyValue.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.<init>(KeyValue.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.<init>(KeyValue.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.<clinit>(KeyValue.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants.<clinit>(HConstants.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.<clinit>(HTableDescriptor.java:1488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSTableDescriptors.<init>(FSTableDescriptors.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init>(HMasterCommandLine.java:307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:139)
    ... 7 more
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this error ?
Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

The exception causing this is `NoClassDefFoundError` which usually means you are missing something from your classpath. In this you're missing `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes` which comes from `hbase-common.jar`. However, if one is missing, there are probably others too. This might mean you're starting HBase the wrong way. Have you tried the included start-up scripts?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have tried the start-up scripts already. I will try to resolve the dependencies